# База данных и таблицы задаваемые при установке 1с bitrix

Tags: mysql, база-данных, битрикс, установка, настройки

При установке bitrix на одном из шагов указал базу данных mysql bitrixusers (она была пустой, не содержала ни одну таблицу). На одном из следующих шагов выдало ошибку

```
DB query error
Please try later
```

Помогите ее устранить. Я точно не знаю, но подозреваю, что база данных bitrixusers не должна быть пустой, а должна иметь определенную структуру. (какие поля она должна содержать и какие типы данных должны иметь поля)
После изменения строки в файле /bitrix/php_interface/dbconn.php

```
$DBDebug = true;
```

(false поменял на true)
Получил ошибку
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После поисков по файлам нашел следующую таблицу b_forum_stat, созданную с помощью следующего скрипта

```
CREATE TABLE b_forum_stat (
    ID bigint(20) not null auto_increment,
    USER_ID int(10) default NULL,
    IP_ADDRESS varchar(128) default NULL,
    PHPSESSID varchar(255) default NULL,
    LAST_VISIT datetime default NULL,
    SITE_ID char(2) default NULL,
    FORUM_ID smallint(5) NOT NULL default '0',
    TOPIC_ID int(10) default NULL,
    SHOW_NAME varchar(101) default NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(ID),
    INDEX IX_B_FORUM_STAT_SITE_ID(SITE_ID, LAST_VISIT),
    INDEX IX_B_FORUM_STAT_TOPIC_ID(TOPIC_ID, LAST_VISIT),
    INDEX IX_B_FORUM_STAT_FORUM_ID(FORUM_ID, LAST_VISIT),
    INDEX IX_B_FORUM_STAT_PHPSESSID(PHPSESSID)
);
```

Comment: Из вашего описания сложилось впечатление, что вы базу данных с таблицей путаете.

Comment: если вы действительно устанавливаете новый экземпляр битрикса, то таблицы установятся сами. Судя по ошибке производится попытка удалить статистику форума с датой менее `''`. На это и выдается ошибка, что значение даты некорректно. В общем мало информации